# Detect space or character in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is that when i press backspace key then I want to find out that it removed space or a character in the rich text box.
How it will be solve.

Thanks in advance.

Amit Garg

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to listen to the [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpreviewkeydown.aspx) event on the Rich Text Box.

```
richTextBox1.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(richTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown);

private void richTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
     {
          //char charToBeDeleted = richTextBox1.Text[richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1];
          char charToBeDeleted = richTextBox1.Text[richTextBox1.SelectionStart - 1];

     }
}
```

Note: This event is (as the name states) fired before the RTB text value is changed.

EDIT: Hans brought up a excellent point that I was making the assumption that the cursor is always at the end, which most certainly won't always be the case. I've added a fix using the SelectionStart property, which will give us the index where the cursor started. Once again, this solution overlooks users selecting multiple characters of text, as the wording of the original questions seems to be aimed at only removing a single character.

Comment: Do you get the correct character-to-be-deleted when the cursor is in the middle of the text?

Answer (score 0):

For exapmle, you can try KeyDown event to remember the initial state of textbox, and using OnTextChanged event to find out the new one state and compare them.
(look [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-get-removed-character-textbox-t3792474.html))